# How to get path after build java application

Tags: java, file

Hello when i clean a build application "Application.jar" how i can get path to file with this application folder for example I have builded this aplication in

`D:/Application/Application.jar`

and want get path

`D:/Application/files/text.txt`

but I dont want to use file chooser I want automatic path. Thanks for answers.

Comment: What do you mean by I don't want to use file chooser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something along these lines:

```
Application.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()
```

This should return something like "D:/Application/" after that you can append the rest of the path you have.